# What are the outcomes of each experimental option in the Vault-Tec Workshop DLC?

Tags: fallout-4

In the Fallout 4 Vault-Tec Workshop DLC, there are four experiments and three options per experiment, for a total of 12 unique workshop items, but you can only have four.

In order to make the best decision, I'd like to know what the stats of each option are.

Answer (score 1):

All of the outcomes of the different experiments are listed [here](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/23792-fallout-4-vault-tec-dlc-prototype-experiment-results-and-conclusions.html).

The Fallout 4 wikia pages seem to have incomplete information, but the links for these are here, in case you were interested:

- [Power Cycle 1000](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Cycle_1000)
- [Soda Fountain](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Soda_fountain)
- [Phoropter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Phoropter)
- [Slot Machine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Slot_machine)